# Como criar um botão play/pause com font awesome

Tags: javascript, css

Oi estou tentando fazer o botão Play/Pause ser apenas um botão porém mantendo as duas IDS, **porque cada ID faz uma função**, alguem sabe como fazer unificar os botões transformando em um apenas. Ao clicar no pause aparece o icone do play, ao clica no play o icone do pause.
Ja li bastante mais não consegui.

```css
#myBtn i{
        font-size: 30px;
        margin-left: 60px;
        color: #000;    
        z-index: 999;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        }


#myBtn2 i{
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #000;    
        z-index: 999;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="myBtn"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div id="myBtn2"><i class="fa fa-pause" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma opção sem JS, mas ai vc precisa seguir a estrutura do HTML, pois ela depende dos seletores do CSS para mostrar um e esconder o outro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu deixei os rádios visíveis para vc poder testar, mas é só esconde-los depois descomentando a CSS que deixei. Seria legal vc usar alguns `aria` atributos para dar mais semântica para o seu componente!

```css
.controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}
.controls label {
  position: absolute;
}
#myBtn,
#myBtn2 {
  display: none;
}
#play:checked ~ .controls #myBtn,
#pause:checked ~ .controls #myBtn2 {
  display: block;
}
/* depois desconemte esse CSS para esconder os Radios 
[name="player"] {
  display: none;
}
*/
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="player">
  <input type="radio" name="player" id="play" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="player" id="pause">
  <div class="controls">
    <label id="myBtn" for="pause"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
    <label id="myBtn2" for="play"><i class="fa fa-pause" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Entendi cara, valeu mesmo, bem ninja vc. Obrigadaoo ai, vou marcar a pergunta, resolveu o problema aqui, Boa tarde.

Comment: @Lucas valeu a força ai man! Que bom que deu certo pra vc ai